# AC blower unit stops working intermittent

Tags: hvac, blower, relay, air

Recently my central AC's blower unit stops working intermittently after its been on for a few days with no issues. When it stops working, I will wait a few hours and then turn on the thermostat to AC and it will work again. It might work for several days or a week with no issues.

When the blower unit stops working the outdoor condenser is on and working. So I know the issue is with the inside coil blower unit itself. I have to go up in the attic but I suspect its a relay/contactor, I believe I have a relay, its a 2 pole 20 amp breaker, or its the capacitor. I know I haven't done any troubleshooting but what does this sound like to you? Is it a capacitor, relay or actual blower unit going bad. That is the most common point of failure? I ask because I want to at least have a clue before going up in the hot attic and doing basic troubleshooting with a voltmeter. The other thing is I can only troubleshoot when it stops working, I'm assuming, in order to look for the missing voltages!?.

Comment: anytime i hear "intermittent", i first suspect heat. i would try replacing the air filter. it could be clogged and causing the fan to overheat and fallback to some sort of protection mechanism. It's a cheap option that very well might help.

Comment: Hi, i did check the filter and it was clean. I had the tech come over and he stated that it was low on gas, the freon and superheat levels were low. Hopefully this is the issue  and not the blower. I will monitor it and update the thread.

Answer (score 2):

So this ended up being the run capacitor. The capacitor was tested and it was found to be below spec/faulty. With a bad run capacitor you don't get smooth power to the blower motor. The motor works overly hard, goes into thermal safety because it overheats, and shuts down. I did decide to replace both the motor and capacitor since the blower more is about 30 years old. Just wanted to post in case someone else had a similar issue.

Comment: Funny this was the first line in my answer last year. This is the reason I quit coming probably time to let all the internet only electricians run the show again.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a good chance the cap could be failing but we don’t just jump to that being the problem with the limited info provided.

It could also be the system is icing up blocking the airflow and causing the motor to overheat. Small motors have thermal overloads that when they get hot trip snd allow the motor to cool down.

A blocked coil from icing can cause the motor to overheat and several hours later when the ice is gone things work until it ices up again.

What causes icing? Several things can cause icing but the most common is low refrigerant. If taken care of prior to the system really getting low and pulling in air & moisture causing further problems a simple top up may be all that is needed.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to get up in the attic next time it happens and look for ice. The lower refrigerant, icing never crossed my mind as reason for this issue as it blows cold air when working but I guess I just have to look when it stops working. Thanks again for your insight!

Comment: It is a catch 22 thing, if the coil ices it reduces the airflow. If the airflow is reduced the coil ices. Check if there is any way the air from the blower can bypass the coil, it should not. Even a register between the fan and coil can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is what you will see with a low charge on a air conditioning system. In a refrigeration system the temperature and pressure are directly related. It is like boiling water but at a much lower temperature. When there is not enough freon, the pressure lowers in the evaporator coil which gets colder. It can and does go below freezing causing ice etc to form on the coil and associated tubing. This colder temperature will keep all of the freon from boiling drawing heat out of the evaporator coil and allow liquid to head back to the compressor.

I will take a SWAG and say the blower probably does not stop but the air flow does. Turning it off allows the evaporator to defrost raising all the temperatures to an operating point. I would venture to say you have ice on the larger tube going to the AC unit outside. All that cold would be in your house with a correct charge.

My advice call the guy back and have him charge it before it destroys itself and you have to replace it to stay cool.

Comment: HI, thanks for your comment, so  I did call the AC guy back and he says there is freon and its fully charge. When the AC stops working the blower does stop working, you cannot hear it on the intake and the filter does not get sucked up. Im assuming I should hear the blower and the filter should get sucked up even is the coils are frozen and no air is coming from the vents. The outside line has ice, I haven't looked upstairs but im sure the coils are iced up. Does this sound like it could be the blower motor overworking and getting shutdown?

Comment: I would give it a good eyeball. It sounds like you are correct but since it worked before?? Has the blower been speeded up? If so that would put more load on the motor. Check and be sure all the dampers are open and that there is not something like another filter you have not found. If you can get a clamp amp meter see if the motor is drawing in spec. Normally if a fan gets plugged at the inlet it draws less power, if on the outlet it draws more power. Reason  power is used to move air against a head, the more air or pressure the more power it requires.

Comment: No other filters, all registers are opened. I will replace the motor at the end of the season and report back. Thanks